# Prove this function is continuous at all points to conclude a topological space is connected

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

I need to show whether the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ is connected in $\mathbb R^2$ with topology induced by $d_1$. I have changed it to polar coordinates and constructed the following: $$f:[0,2\pi ) \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2, \ \ \ f(\alpha ) = (2\cos (\alpha ), 2\sin (\alpha ))$$

I am trying to show that $f$ is continuous at every $\alpha$ which would show $f$ is continuous and then I may conclude that since $[0,2\pi )$ is connected and $f$ is a continuous map between topological spaces, the image is also connected, but I am unsure as to how to start this at all.

Comment: Can you use $d_2$ instead of $d_1$?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metric to prove continuity.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to \alpha} d(f(x),f(\alpha)) &= \lim_{x\to \alpha} 2(|\cos x - \cos \alpha|+|\sin x - \sin \alpha|) \newline
&=0
\end{align*}

This last limit you need to use $\cos$, $\sin$ and absolute value continuity.